# Muliple hidden fullscreen divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on my portfolio website, but can't solve the following problem.

The website is basically just pictures, if you click on one,
a semi-transparent fullscreen div opens with information (more pics and some text).
If you click again the div will close.

jQuery for hiding and showing:

```
<script>
$(function()
{
    $('.masonryImage').click(function()
    {
        $('.hiddenDiv').show();
        $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
    });
    $('.hiddenDiv').click(function()
    {
        $('.hiddenDiv').hide();
        $("body").css("overflow", "auto");
    });
});
</script
```

HTML:

```
<div class="masonryImage">
        <img src="images/pic1.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div class="hiddenDiv">
     <div class="text">
         <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
     </div>
     <div class="pics">
         <img src="images/pic2.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
</div>
```

So far it works with one picture, but when I'm adding another,
the new hidden text will overlay the first one, same with the pictures.

Is it because I'm using the same class ("masonryImage")?
Or isn't my Javascript removing the divs properly?

Many thanks.

Edit: CSS might be usefull:

```
.hiddenDiv {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    z-index:900;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:none;
    overflow: scroll;
 }

.masonryImage {

     margin: 20px 20px 20px;
     display: inline-block;
     cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Comment: can you replicate your issue in jsfiddle?

Comment: See http://masonry.desandro.com/appendix.html#imagesloaded and for demo http://desandro.github.io/masonry/docs/intro.html#imagesloaded_plugin

Comment: *Or isn't my Java removing the divs properly?* - Java isn't Javascript

Comment: ok this code might conflict other divs. As you are using classes, if all the hidden Divs have same class they all show up at once and when you close one div it closes all divs. Now what you have to do is to right some thing like this `$('.masonryImage').click(function(){ $(this).next().show(); //it will show only hiddenDiv next to that image })` and when you close the div right `$(this).hide()`. I hope you understand.

Comment: Thanks man, simple and working well.

Comment: its because your hiddendiv is a class and when you select it, all matching elements will show/hide, just be more precise with your selector, yo

Answer (score 0):

here is how I modified your code :

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9KeM4/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="masonryImage">
    <img src="..." alt="">
        
        <div class="hiddenDiv">
            <div class="text">
                <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
            </div>
            <div class="pics">
                <img src="..." alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I put the `hiddenDiv` inside the `masonryImage` so every `masonryImage` will have a custom `hiddenDiv` to show/hide.

**JQUERY**

```
$('.masonryImage').click(function()
{
    if ($(this).find('.hiddenDiv').toggle().is(":visible")) {
        //alert('hiddenDiv is visible !');
        $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
    }
    else {
        //alert('hiddenDiv is hidden !');
        $("body").css("overflow", "auto");
    }
});
```

You can just use `.toogle()` to show/hide the div. `$(this)` refers to the clicked `masonryImage` and `.find('.hiddenDiv')` to its child (you can also use `.children('.hiddenDiv')` ).
Then you can test if the clicked div is hidden or visible with `.is(":visible")`, to apply your body custom css :)

Hope I helped you.